# Export Django Database into YAML file

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, yaml

I know you can easily import a YAML file into a Django database (in order to populate the database before starting the project for instance) but how can I do the opposite (ie save the complete database into a single .yaml file).

I read there is a way to export one single table into a file:

```
YAMLSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("yaml")
yaml_serializer = YAMLSerializer()
with open("file.yaml", "w") as out:
    yaml_serializer.serialize(SomeModel.objects.all(), stream=out)
```

but I need to do it on the complete database (which has many tables with complex relations between each ones).

I could write a script to do that for me, but I don't want to redo something which has probably been done already, and I wouldn't know how to do it the better way so that Django has no difficulties to read it after.

So far, I've been working on a SQLITE3 database engine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need the [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) management command.

```
pip install pyyaml
python manage.py dumpdata --format=yaml > /path/to/dump_file.yaml
```

Comment: The cool thing is that yaml can be used as a fixture too, with `loaddata`

Comment: don't for get to run  `pip install pyyaml` first. Otherwise you'll get `CommandError: Unable to serialize database: No module named yaml`

Comment: add to this answer, if you just use the `python manage.py dumpdata > test.json` it will ouput json format and you don't need install pyyaml