# how to Django dumpdata nested models in yaml

Tags: django, pyyaml, dumpdata

So I have this awesome Django app which gives me satisfaction and such.
But now the problem, I want to use `dumpdata` (or something that does the same) to export a model with a nested other model in yaml format.

Lets say I have two models, `Project` and `Questions`. Each `Project` can have it's owns set of `Questions`.

The code looks something like this:

Project Model:

```
class Projects(SortableMixin):
    """
    Some docstring
    """
    slug = models.SlugField(
            _('slug'),
            help_text=_('Short name to address this projects from templates.'))
    # Basic fields
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(_('name'), help_text=_('The question.'))
    # Some other fields...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, blank=True)
```

Questions Model:

```
class Question(SortableMixin):
    """
    Some docstring
    """
    slug = models.SlugField(
        _('slug'),
        help_text=_('Short name to address this question from templates.'))
    # Basic fields
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(_('name'), help_text=_('The question.'))
    input = models.TextField()
```

The `Project` model has his own app and so has the `Questions`.
The structure looks like this:

```
- Django
  - Apps
    - Project
    - Questions
```

Whenever I want to export my database I'll do the following:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --indent 4 --format yaml > dbdump.yaml
```

Although this works, and I can later import it with `LoadData`, its not what I want, the output of the yaml file looks crappy. I want to have a nice nested model looking yaml file for review purposes, below the crappy looking file:

Projects section:

```
-   model: project.projects
    pk: 1
    fields: {slug: "slugproject1", object_id: 10, name: "some project 1", question: ["slugquestion1"]}
-   model: project.projects
    pk: 2
    fields: {slug: "slugproject2", object_id: 11, name: "some project 2", question: ["slugquestion2"]}
-   model: project.projects
    pk: 3
    fields: {slug: "slugproject3", object_id: 12, name: "some project 3", question: ["slugquestion3"]}
```

Questions section:

```
-   model: question.question
    pk: 1
    fields: {slug: "slugquestion1", object_id: 100, name: "some question 1", input: "q1"}
-   model: question.question
    pk: 1
    fields: {slug: "slugquestion2", object_id: 200, name: "some question 2", input: "q2"}
-   model: question.question
    pk: 1
    fields: {slug: "slugquestion3", object_id: 300, name: "some question 3", input: "q3"}
```

What I really want is to export the yaml file like so:

```
-   model: project.projects
    pk: 1
    fields: {
        slug: "slugproject1", 
        object_id: 10, 
        name: "some project 1", 
        questions: {
            model: question.question
            pk: 1
            fields: {
                 slug: "slugquestion1"
                 object_id: 100
                 name: "some question 1"
                 input: "q1"
            }            
        }
    }
-   model: project.projects
    pk: 2
    fields: {
        slug: "slugproject2", 
        object_id: 11, 
        name: "some project 2", 
        questions: {
            model: question.question
            pk: 2
            fields: {
                 slug: "slugquestion2"
                 object_id: 200
                 name: "some question 2"
                 input: "q2"
            }            
        }
    }
-   model: project.projects
    pk: 3
    fields: {
        slug: "slugproject3", 
        object_id: 13, 
        name: "some project 3", 
        questions: {
            model: question.question
            pk: 3
            fields: {
                 slug: "slugquestion3"
                 object_id: 300
                 name: "some question 3"
                 input: "q3"
            }            
        }
    }
```

To achieve this I implemented a custom serialiser inside projects:

```
- Django
  - Apps
    - Project
      - Management
        - Commands
          - test.py
    - Questions
```

The code looks like:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from apps.project import Projects
from apps.questions import Question
from rest_framework import serializers
import yaml


class QuestionSerialier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('pk', 'slug', 'object_id', 'name', 'input')


class ProjectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerialier(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ('pk', 'slug','object_id', 'name', 'questions')


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ''

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        with open('result.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
            for i in Projects.objects.filter():
                yaml.dump(ProjectsSerializer(i).data, 
                                yaml_file,
                                default_flow_style=False,
                                allow_unicode=False,
                                encoding=None)
```

I can run the code by running:

```
./manage.py test
```

Only this exports my models like so:

```
- project: 1
  pk: 1
  slug: "slugproject1"
  object_id: 10
  name: "some project 1"
  questions:
  - !!python/object/apply:collections.OrderedDict
    - - - pk
      - - slug
      - - object_id
      - - name
      - - input
- project: 2
  pk: 2
  slug: "slugproject2"
  object_id: 11
  name: "some project 2"
  questions:
  - !!python/object/apply:collections.OrderedDict
    - - - pk
      - - slug
      - - object_id
      - - name
      - - input
- project: 3
  pk: 3
  slug: "slugproject3"
  object_id: 12
  name: "some project 3"
  questions:
  - !!python/object/apply:collections.OrderedDict
    - - - pk
      - - slug
      - - object_id
      - - name
      - - input
```

As you can see the above is not usable for import or even readable export...

Can you guys point me in the right direction on how to achieve a nested models dumpdata yaml export in django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out how to handle the export/import.

To export to a proper yaml file format I did the following:

```
...
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    with open('result.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
        model = serializer.Meta.model
        json_object = []
        json_data = json.dumps(serializer(model_data).data)
        json_object.append(json.loads(json_data))

        yaml.dump(
            json_object,
            yaml_file,
            default_flow_style=False,
            allow_unicode=False,
            encoding=None
        )
```

This export to a proper yaml file.

Then to import the yaml file I did the following:

```
...
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with open('result.yaml', 'r') as yaml_file:
            yaml_list = yaml.load(yaml_file.read())
            for data in yaml_list:
                ...process file
```

And that's it!

Comment: Without implementing a Django `Command` / using a package (much simpler) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21183842/4916945